# Find in a map using the base class with a boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I'm looking for a way to find an element inside a map using the base class (the code bellow is just a basic example):

```
#include <map>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class Base {
public:
    Base(int v) : id(v) {};
    int id;  
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int v) : Base(v) {};
};


int main()
{
    std::map<boost::shared_ptr<Derived>, double> m;
    m.insert(std::make_pair(boost::shared_ptr<Derived>(new Derived(1)), 10));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(boost::shared_ptr<Derived>(new Derived(2)), 20));

    auto b1 = boost::shared_ptr<Base>(new Base(1));
    m.find(b1);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I want to compare the `id` attribute. The errors returned by the compiler are the following:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:35:14: error: no matching function for call to 'std::map<boost::shared_ptr<Derived>, double>::find(boost::shared_ptr<Base>&)'
     m.find(b1);
              ^
main.cpp:35:14: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:61:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:820:7: note: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::find(const key_type&) [with _Key = boost::shared_ptr<Derived> _Tp = double; _Compare = std::less<boost::shared_ptr<Derived> > _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const boost::shared_ptr<Derived>, double> > std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const boost::shared_ptr<Derived>, double> > std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = boost::shared_ptr<Derived>]
       find(const key_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:820:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'boost::shared_ptr<Base>' to 'const key_type& {aka const boost::shared_ptr<Derived>&}'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:835:7: note: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::find(const key_type&) const [with _Key = boost::shared_ptr<Derived> _Tp = double; _Compare = std::less<boost::shared_ptr<Derived> > _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const boost::shared_ptr<Derived>, double> > std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const boost::shared_ptr<Derived>, double> > std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = boost::shared_ptr<Derived>]
       find(const key_type& __x) const
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:835:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'boost::shared_ptr<Base>' to 'const key_type& {aka const boost::shared_ptr<Derived>&}'
```

Comment: should be a map of Base shared pointers here

Comment: @Kiroxas Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to search into a map of Derivate shared pointers using a Base shared pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use your map for lookup by `id`, you need to pass in an appropriate comparison function so that the map sorts its keys by `id` instead of the default `operator <` (which, I believe, compares ownership block addresses with `boost::shared_ptr` arguments).

So change the map like this:

```
struct Less_id
{
  bool operator() (const boost::shared_ptr<Derived> &lhs, const boost::shared_ptr<Derived> &rhs) const
  {
    return lhs->id < rhs->id;
  }
};

typedef std::map<boost::shared_ptr<Derived>, double, Less_id> Map;

Map m;
```

This will sort the map accordingly, but still not allow lookup by `Base` pointer. To do that, you can write your own function above [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

```
Map::const_iterator find_base(const Map &map, const boost::shared_ptr<Base> &base)
{
  auto it = std::lower_bound(
    map.begin(), map.end(), base,
    [](const Map::value_type &lhs, const boost::shared_ptr<Base> &rhs)
    { return lhs.first->id < rhs->id; }
  );
  if (it != map.end() && it->first->id == base->id)
    return it;
  else
    return map.end();
}
```

`std::lower_bound()` is used to keep the logarithmic complexity `std::map::find()` offers.

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/RWRtEq)

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues to overcome. The first is that you want to search for a `Base` in a collection of `Derived`s. The second is that you want to compare by value rather than by address. **The other answers are neglecting this second point**. Try `std::find_if`:

```
auto b1 = boost::shared_ptr<Base>(new Base(1));
auto itFound = std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end()
   [=](const std::pair<boost::shared_ptr<Derived>, double>& pair)
   {
      // omitting null checks for this example
      return pair.first->id == b1->id;
   });
```

And if the requirement is really just to find a key with the given id, you could make it simpler:

```
int queryKey = 1;
auto itFound = std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end()
   [=](const std::pair<boost::shared_ptr<Derived>, double>& pair)
   {
      return pair.first->id == queryKey;
   });
```

Now, as noted in the comments, this will give you linear rather than `map`'s usual logarithmic lookup time. If the map is small it won't matter, but if this is an issue, you could use `std::lower_bound` instead of `find_if`. Note that this would also require adding a custom comparer so you could ensure the map's sort order was based on id. For example:

```
struct Compare
{
   bool operator()(const boost::shared_ptr<Derived>& l,
      const boost::shared_ptr<Derived>& r) const
   {
      // omitting null checks for this example
      return l->id < r->id;
   }
};

std::map<boost::shared_ptr<Derived>, double, Compare> m;
```

Comment: The downside is that `std::find_if` will use the range simply as a sequence, and neglect the lookup structure above it - giving linear instead of logarithmic performance. `std::lower_bound` could be a better candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Use an

```
std::map<boost::shared_ptr<Derived>, double, std::less<boost::shared_ptr<Base>>>
```

**Edit**: I am ahead of the times - this only works for C++14.

Comment: The problem is that (at least until C++14 is out), `find()` requires a `const key_type&`, so it needs a `boost::shared_ptr<Derived>` argument.

Answer (score 0):

This is because boost::shared_ptr's  operator < is not what you want, you need a delegation to the Derived class's operator <.

use std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare>

for example:

```cpp
 std::map<boost::shared_ptr<Derived>, double, compare_func()> m;
```

Comment: OK, but the problem is: how to implement a compare_func that is going to search inside a map of shared_ptr<Derivate>, using a shared_ptr<Base>.

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for an object `Base` which can only be in the map if it is of type `Derived` you can simply do this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Derived> d1 = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(b1);
if(d1) {
   m.find(d1);
} else {
   // not in the map
}
```

---

As you use `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` as a *key*, another possibility would be to actually use pointers to the base class instead:

Use

```
std::map<boost::shared_ptr<Base>, double> m;
```

instead of

```
std::map<boost::shared_ptr<Derived>, double> m;
```

and everything works as expected.

---

Btw, you are missing a `virtual` destructor in `Base`!

Comment: The code is just a basic example, unfortunately I can't change the map key.

Comment: @HugoJuarezCorrá: I gave another solution which does not require to change the map key.